# How to asynchrony exchange a uri on img

Tags: python, django

There was a problem with Django, namely:
1. There is in template field entry and the

```
<input class="uri-com" placeholder="URL on community" value="" onchange="addComURI(this.value)">
 <img id="fg-photo-50" class="community-50" src="{% static "img/community_50.gif" %}">
```

2. When you add a link to a third-party resource in input, I want to replace the original image, the one that is located on this link. Download to itself under this its not want. I'm replacing the value of the img tag in JS

```
document.getElementById("fg-photo-50").src = this.responseText;
```

The link is replaced but taking into account the connected statics to a template, i.e. before the link adds the address of my host server

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%22https://getcim.com/RwO3inNPejmv9mTnK24R8EESIkhA/V6NXerYvQks
```

(The link is not working)

My addComURI:

```
function addComURI(comm_uri) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'comm_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(comm_uri);
    xhr.open('GET', 'test?' + params, true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState != 4) return;
      if (this.status != 200) {
        alert( 'error: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : 'bad request'));
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById("fg-photo-50").src = this.responseText;
    }
}
```

And the Django code that sends the response:

```
def request_community(request):
    comm_uri = request.GET.get("comm_uri", 1)
    fg_photo= get_community_photo(comm_uri)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(fg_photo), content_type='application/json')

Who will tell you how to properly replace the link to the image?
```

Comment: We need to see the whole `addComURI` function, plus the Django code that sends the response.

Comment: Ok, I'm update my question. Thank you

Comment: Well now you need to show `get_community_photo`. The point is, what is in that response?

Comment: request_community return a string with url 'https://pp.userapi.com/RwO3inNPejmv9mTnK24R8EOguX3ZTWvQESIkhA/V6NXerYvQks.jpg'. If i hardcode set this string to my js function addComURI: ```document.getElementById("fg-photo-50").src =
          'https://pp.userapi.com/RwO3inNPejmv9mTnK24R8EOguX3ZTWvQESIkhA/V6NXerYvQks.jpg';``` Image update on html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get_community_photo function returns a string. But before you return that to the browser, you call `json.dumps()` on it. This has the effect of wrapping it in an extra pair of quotes. So when you assign that response text to the image src, the extra quote is included: that's what `%22` means.

The solution is simply to not do this. Remove `json.dumps` and simply return the value:

```
return HttpResponse(fg_photo)
```